# How to detect changes to dom with no distinguishable ids or classes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on fixing a bug to my google chrome extension for Gmail. I need to detect when the Rich Format bar is displayed, but all of the ids and classes are obfuscated and I presume unreliable.

To detect the message canvas

```
this.canvas_frame_document.evaluate("//iframe[contains(@class, 'editable')]",
   this.canvas_frame_document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
   null);
```

and to detect the Rich Text bar

```
this.canvas_frame_document.evaluate("//img[@command='+underline']",
    this.canvas_frame_document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
```

This works well for composing new emails or the like because the canvas dom exists and thus detectable.

However, when clicking reply, reply to all, or forward doesn't work because the dom is dynamically changed and `chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener` can't detect a change in page as I do for Compose.

Comment: What type of events do you want to listen for?  Do you want to learn when th Rich Format bar begins to exist?

Comment: @strager: Nodes being inserted into the DOM and yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy solution would be to use `jQuery.live()` for this.

If you want to stay hardcore then you can bind your check to `DOMNodeInserted` event that fires when a new element is added to the dom, or if that doesn't catch it then more general `DOMSubtreeModified` event which fires when dom is modified in any way. More about events can be found [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html).

Comment: Ah thanks, I just didn't want to include more javascript to my extension than necessary so its not another extension eating up too many resources. I'll give this a try.

Comment: I used DOMSubtreeModified to catch the changes. Thanks for the help! I found http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php to be helpful.